# Expected no. of children "at least one boy and at least one girl, with boy older than girl"

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation, geometric-probability

A couple decides to keep having children until

1. Cond1: they have at least one boy and at least one girl,
2. Cond2: with boy older than girl

and then stop. Assume they never have twins, that the “trials” are independent with probability $1/2$ of a boy, and that they are fertile enough to keep producing children indefinitely. What is the expected number of children?

Note: updated

If we consider just Cond1, answer would be
Let $X$ be the number of children needed, starting with the 2nd child, to obtain one whose gender is not the same as that of the firstborn. Then $X − 1$ is Geom(1/2), so $E(X) = 2$. This does not include the firstborn, so the expected total number of children is $E(X + 1) = E(X) + 1 = 3$.

Comment: Can you wrote down what you tried? Also, do they stop when they have at least one boy and at least one girl, or do they stop when they have at least one boy and at least one girl, with the boy older than the girl? In the latter case, the probability is 1.

Comment: Hope that update helped, I could not comprehend how to work out the EX with cond 2 I know he answer is 4

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- You want a boy born and then a girl
- What is the expected number of children until the first boy is born?
- Given that the first boy has been born, how many additional children are expected until the next girl is born?
- Use linearity of expectation.

Comment: So EY comprises Cond1 and Cond2, EX comprises Cond1, EY = 2* EX

Answer (score 1):

The two conditions essentially translate into the fact that couple are looking for following birth sequence $BG$ where event $B$ is birth of a boy and event $G$ is birth of a girl.

Till the $BG$ is achieved, lets say that the expected number of births needed are $e$.

Lets say that the expected number of births from the point when last born was a boy, i.e., event $B$ occurred is $f$.

There is $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of each event $B$ and $G$ (mutually exclusive and exhaustive events). Therefore at start,

$e = \frac{1}{2}(1 + e) + \frac{1}{2}(1 + f)$    [$\because$ first term signifies if $G$ happens with $\frac{1}{2}$ probability then from that point state is restored and expected number of births are still $e$]

At point $f$,

$f = \frac{1}{2}(1 + f) + \frac{1}{2}(1)$        [$\because$ first term signifies if $B$ happens with $\frac{1}{2}$ probability then from that point state is restored to point where expected number of births are $f$. Second term corresponds to event $G$]

Solving the two equations, $e = 4$ and $f =2$

$\therefore$ the expected no. of children “at least one boy and at least one girl, with boy older than girl” is $4$

Answer (score 0):

Let the expectation value of a sequence of births whose starting sequence is S as E[S], where S is a string of B (boy) or G (girl). Under the given condition, we have

E[BG] = 2
E[B] = E[BB]/2 + E[BG]/2 = (1 + E[B])/2 + 1
E[G] = E[GB]/2 + E[GG]/2 = (1 + E[B])/2 + (1 + E[G])/2

From the 2nd eq. we got E[B] = 3, and then from 3rd eq. E[G] = 5
Therefore the expectation value is:

E(X) = E[B]/2 + E[G]/2 = 3/2 + 5/2 = 4

I wrote a small python program to validate the answer.

```
import random

nexp = 0  # number of experiment
sum = 0   # sum of kids, expectation value is sum / nexp
while nexp < 500000:
  nexp += 1  # new couple
  B = False  # we have a boy
  S = ''     # kids storage
  while True:      # fertility never ends until break
    g = random.randint(0,1)  # its gender
    S += 'GB'[g] # add new born

    if B and g == 0: # have a boy and new born is a girl
        break

    B |= g == 1  # at least one boy
  sum += len(S)

  if nexp % 1000 == 0:
    print("{}: {} {} {:.4f}".format(nexp, S, len(S), sum/nexp))

# output 
# ....
# 497000: GBBBG 5 4.0004
# 498000: BBBBG 5 4.0005
# 499000: BG 2 4.0004
# 500000: GBBG 4 4.0003 
# We get three digits accuracy after six digits experiments. 
# If one wants six digits accuracy, he or she will do twelve digits experiments.
```